# need help what to do?

Tags: mountain-bike

I have 3 old bikes all have been in a shed out of the weather for about 20 to 25 years. tires are rotted. on has a front fork suspension not working. #1 is a Trex zx 6500 #2 Giant Ricon girls bike and the last one is GT terain outpost. where do i go for parts . I can do the work they all have very very little time riding on them . all the bike stores want to do is sell new bikes but i believe they can be fixed and used again any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have some reading to do, https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help and are good points to start. Source for parts depends very much on where you are located.

Comment: First thing to do is convince yourself that its possible.  If you're handy with tools, this should be mostly straightforward.  Look out for a bicycle cooperative in a town or city near you.  And SE can help, but its structured for definite Q&A questions with defined answers.  You can always try the [chat] where its a bit more casual.  You need 20 rep to join chat, so answer a few questions or ask one with a definite answer (ie not open-ended opinion question.)

Comment: @Blaine In my opinion, the link others have referred you to is a very poor comparison to your situation, I want to encourage you to move forward in your quest to get these bikes up and running.  It certainly won't be a waste of time to get these mostly unused, 20+ year old bikes shined-up and on the road.  Trek, Giant and GT are all quality brand names, and I'm certain that these decades-old bikes are lighter and their drivetrains of better quality (definitely) with smoother functioning (I'll bet ya) than today's department store bikes.